# insertColumn() and update getLastColumn()

Tags: google-apps-script

quick question concerning Google Spreadsheet. When I use `insertColumn()` and sometimes later `getLastColumn` from the sheet, it gives me the last column of the old, un-appended sheet. Even if I store the return of `insertColumn()` in `var newVar` and get do `newVar.getLastColumn()` it doesn't change.

I assume I have a misconception of how `getLastColumn()` works. Can somebody help me out?

Thank you all in advance! :-)

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because there's no content in it, maybe you're looking for `getMaxColumns()`.

From the documentation:

> getLastColumn()
>
> Returns the position of the last column that has content.

> getMaxColumns()
>
> The maximum width of the sheet, regardless of content.